# Angular - mapping API Response Objects to key - value pairs

Tags: angular, laravel, api, rest, mapping

I am trying to read from Laravel API using Angular but could not get a itemized key-value pairs out of it.

app.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  
  products = [];

  constructor (private dataService: DataService ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.sendGetRequest().subscribe((data: any = [])=>{
      console.log(data);
      this.products = data;
    });
  }
}
```

My DataService class reading from API : data.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, JsonpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  private REST_API_SERVER = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/assets";

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public sendGetRequest(){
    
    return this.httpClient.get(this.REST_API_SERVER);
    
  }
}
```

All I get is a list of Objects :

[image]

I tried Angular's "map" operator but still getting the same list of objects. Any ideas ? What is the best way of reading the actual data inside these objects ?

Thanks

Comment: ... ` return return this.httpClient.get(this.REST_API_SERVER).pipe ( map( data => transformerOnData(data))) ... ` (give example of your json from server, and how you would want to transform it )

Comment: ( just a sample (in ReactiveForm, but idea is the sampe on observables) on jxjs `map` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69755402/2499866

Comment: @Vovan_Super just added the json. I'd like to get it as an array in key-value pairs. There are nested layers  in json coming from different tables, so not sure how I can drill down into these.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was not sending a proper JSON object on the API side. Below has solved the issue. Values are not coming as "object" anymore but proper JSON sets.

return response()->json($resp);

I hope that helps someone in the future.